# Converting duration to years in Java8 Date API?

Tags: java, date, java-8, duration, java-time

I have a date in the far past. 
I found out what the duration is between this date and now. 
Now I would like to know - how much is this in years?

I came up withthis solution using Java8 API. 
This is a monstrous solution, since I have to convert the duration to Days manually first, because there will be an `UnsupportedTemporalTypeException` otherwise - `LocalDate.plus(SECONDS)` is not supported for whatever reason. 
Even if  the compiler allows this call.

Is there a less verbous possibility to convert `Duration` to years?

```
LocalDate dateOne = LocalDate.of(1415, Month.JULY, 6);
Duration durationSinceGuss1 = Duration.between(LocalDateTime.of(dateOne, LocalTime.MIDNIGHT),LocalDateTime.now());

long yearsSinceGuss = ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(LocalDate.now(), 
        LocalDate.now().plus(
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.toDays(
                        durationSinceGuss1.getSeconds()), 
                ChronoUnit.DAYS) );

/*
 * ERROR - 
 * LocalDate.now().plus(durationSinceGuss1) causes an Exception. 
 * Seconds are not Supported for LocalDate.plus()!!!
 * WHY OR WHY CAN'T JAVA DO WHAT COMPILER ALLOWS ME TO DO?
 */
//long yearsSinceGuss = ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(LocalDate.now(), LocalDate.now().plus(durationSinceGuss) );

/*
 * ERROR - 
 * Still an exception! 
 * Even on explicitly converting duration to seconds. 
 * Everything like above. Seconds are just not allowed. Have to convert them manually first e.g. to Days?!
 * WHY OR WHY CAN'T YOU CONVERT SECONDS TO DAYS OR SOMETHING AUTOMATICALLY, JAVA?
 */
//long yearsSinceGuss = ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(LocalDate.now(), LocalDate.now().plus(durationSinceGuss.getSeconds(), ChronoUnit.SECONDS) );
```

Comment: You calculate the Duration between a date in the *past* and `now()`, then try to calculate the years between `now()` and *another date* that is Duration into the *future*. WHY?!?!? --- Example: This year (2016) is a leap year, but leap day haven't happened yet. Duration from `Feb 3, 2015` to today (`Feb 3, 2016`) last year is 365 days. 365 days from now is *yesterdays* date of next year (`Feb 2, 2017`). So exactly one year from original date, but your calculation would say that future date is less than one year from now. Result incorrect!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried using `LocalDateTime` or `DateTime` instead of `LocalDate`? By design, the latter does not support hours/minutes/seconds/etc, hence the `UnsupportedTemporalTypeException` when you try to add seconds to it.

For example, this works:

```
LocalDateTime dateOne = LocalDateTime.of(1415, Month.JULY, 6, 0, 0);
Duration durationSinceGuss1 = Duration.between(dateOne, LocalDateTime.now());
long yearsSinceGuss = ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(LocalDateTime.now(), LocalDateTime.now().plus(durationSinceGuss1) );
System.out.println(yearsSinceGuss); // prints 600
```

Comment: Indeed, `plus` of `LocalDateTime` works with seconds! Or Even with `Duration` itselfe!

Answer (score 5):

Use `Period` to get the number of years between two `LocalDate` objects:

```
    LocalDate before    = LocalDate.of(1415, Month.JULY, 6);
    LocalDate now       = LocalDate.now();
    Period    period    = Period.between(before, now);

    int yearsPassed     = period.getYears();

    System.out.println(yearsPassed);
```

Comment: Hi! I am aware of periods. This all was about converting DURATION to years, e.g. if someone passes it to you from outside.

Comment: Personally I find day precision (using `Period`) much more appealing in historic context than second precision (using `Duration`). However, constructing `LocalDate.of(1415, Month.JULY, 6)` is probably wrong because `java.time` only uses the gregorian calendar rules for all times.

Answer (score 3):

Although the accepted answer of @Matt Ball tries to be clever in usage of the Java-8-API, I would throw in following objection:

**Your requirement is not exact because there is no way to exactly convert seconds to years.**

Reasons are:

- Most important: Months have different lengths in days (from 28 to 31).
- Years have sometimes leap days (29th of February) which have impact on calculating year deltas, too.
- Gregorian cut-over: You start with a year in 1415 which is far before first gregorian calendar reform which cancelled full ten days, in England even 11 days and in Russia more. And years in old Julian calendar have different leap year rules.
- Historic dates are not defined down to second precision. Can you for example describe the instant/moment of the battle of Hastings? We don't even know the exact hour, just the day. Assuming midnight at start of day is already a rough and probably wrong assumption.
- Timezone effects which have impact on the length of day (23h, 24h, 25h or even different other lengths).
- Leap seconds (exotic)

And maybe the most important objection to your code:

**I cannot imagine that the supplier of the date with year 1415 has got the intention to interprete such a date as gregorian date.**

I understand the wish for **conversion from seconds to years** but it **can only be an approximation** whatever you choose as solution. So if you have years like 1415 I would just suggest following very simple approximation:

```
Duration d = ...;
int approximateYears = (int) (d.toDays() / 365.2425);
```

For me, it is sufficient in historic context as long as we really want to use a second-based duration for such an use-case. It seems you cannot change the input you get from external sources (otherwise it would be a good idea to contact the duration supplier and ask if the count of days can be supplied instead). Anyway, you have to ask yourself what kind of year definition you want to apply.

**Side notes:**

Your complaint "WHY OR WHY CAN'T JAVA DO WHAT COMPILER ALLOWS ME TO DO?" does not match the character of new java.time-API.

You expect the API to be type-safe, but **`java.time` (JSR-310) is not designed as type-safe and heavily relies on runtime-exceptions**. The compiler will not help you with this API. Instead you have to consult the documentation in case of doubt if any given time unit is applicable on any given temporal type. You can find such an answer in the documentation of any concrete implementation of [Temporal.isSupported(TemporalUnit)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/Temporal.html#isSupported-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-). Anyway, the wish for compile-safety is understandable (and I have myself done my best to implement my own time library Time4J as type-safe) but the design of JSR-310 is already set in stone.

There is also a subtile pitfall if you apply a `java.time.Duration` on either `LocalDateTime` or `Instant` because the results are not exactly comparable (seconds of first type are defined on local timeline while seconds of `Instant` are defined on global timeline). So even if there is no runtime exception like in the accepted answer of @Matt Ball, we have to carefully consider if the result of such a calculation is reasonable and trustworthy.

Comment: Hey Meno!I understand your point and somehow I understand the strategy, which the new Date API is following. Throw an exception, if an exceact solution is not possible.

BUT. Java somehow DID implement the conversion of days, months etc. to years. 
So why should the conversion of seconds (and so durations) should be different?
The current API feels like a minefield for me. I would appretiate approximations instead of runtime exceptions.

Comment: @Skip Well, a plain calendar date (like `LocalDate`) has no relationship to seconds, the granularity of calendar dates is not defined in such a precision. Therefore it is a good thing to not support applying second-based durations on calendar dates. So users can be warned when ever they make precision errors. It is not so good however that the compiler does not complain about such code so the new API can indeed be sometimes a minefield at runtime. This behaviour relates to all uses of static `from()`-methods or low-level-interfaces `Temporal`, `TemporalUnit` etc.

Comment: @Skip By the way, I don't see any automatic conversion from days to years (because of different month length) unless you define a reference date. And I think, `Period` has no mechanism for such a conversion. Do you know it better?

Comment: A Plain calendar date may not have a relationship to seconds. What I am crying about is the following: `LocalDate.now().plus().(days, ChronoUnit.DAYS) // legal` but `LocalDate.now().plus().(duration) // NOT legal` . Even if it is known, how to convert duration's unit (which are seconds) to days and java provides API to do so. `long days = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toDays(duration.getSeconds()), ChronoUnit.DAYS)` So for me it is one more unnessessary mine during the runtime. And this is not the only one

Comment: By converting days to years I ment the expression, using `ChronoUnit.YEAR.between()` which may not return correct results, as you stated above correctly.